# JoinAcross on nested association by nested key

Tags: associations

I would like to join two associations on nested keys.  Is this possible?

```
first = {<|"away" -> <|"name" -> "bob", "money" -> 10 |>, "home" -> <|"name" -> "Sue", "money" -> 15 |>|>, <|"away" -> <|"name" -> "Joe", "money" -> 20 |>, "home" -> <|"name" -> "Jane", "money" -> 25 |>|>}

second = {<|"away" -> <|"name" -> "bob", "Sex" -> "male" |>,  "home" -> <|"name" -> "Sue", "sex" -> "female"|>|>, <|"away" -> <|"name" -> "Joe", "Sex" -> "Male" |>, "home" -> <|"name" -> "Jane", "Sex" -> "Female" |>|>}

result=JoinAcross[first, second, ?? ?]
```

What I would like is:

```
result = {<|"away" -> <|"name" -> "bob", "money" -> 10, "Sex" -> "male"|>, "home" -> <|"name" -> "Sue", "money" -> 15, "sex" -> "female"|>|>, <|"away" -> <|"name" -> "Joe", "money" -> 20, "Sex" -> "Male"|>, "home" -> <|"name" -> "Jane", "money" -> 25, "Sex" -> "Female"|>|>}
```

It does not work on just the "away" key due to the "away" key in first and second not being exactly the same and JoinAcross[first,second,"Outer"] just yields a Join.

Is it possible to join across a nested key?

I have tried

```
JoinAcross[first, second, "away"]
```

and several variations with zero success.

Thank you.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`JoinAcross` cannot reference subparts.  The desired result can be obtained using the following expression:

```
GatherBy[Join[first, second], #[[All, "name"]] &] // Map[Merge[Association]]

% === result
(* True *)
```

This is basically equivalent to using `JoinAcross` with full-outer-join semantics.

**Explanation**

The ultimate goal is to relationally join associations by a composite key consisting of the *away* and *home* name values.  That is, for each association `a` we wish to use the key `a[[All, "name"]]`, e.g.:

```
First[first][[All, "name"]]

(* <| "away" -> "bob", "home" -> "Sue" |>
```

We could been more explicit about the outer key names by using `{"away", "home"}` instead of `All`, but we will stick with the shorter form for now.

Unfortunately, `JoinAcross` only permits `Key` syntax, and `Key` does not presently support subpart references.  We have little option but to implement the join directly ourselves.

In order to merge related associations from the two lists `first` and `second`, we need to gather those associations together using the desired composite key:

```
GatherBy[Join[first, second], #[[All, "name"]] &]

(*
{ { <| "away" -> <|"name"->"bob","money"->10|>
     , "home" -> <|"name"->"Sue","money"->15|>
     |>
  , <| "away" -> <|"name"->"bob","Sex"->"male"|>
     , "home" -> <|"name"->"Sue","sex"->"female"|>
     |>
  }
, { <| "away" -> <|"name"->"Joe","money"->20|>
     , "home" -> <|"name"->"Jane","money"->25|>
     |>
  , <| "away" -> <|"name"->"Joe","Sex"->"Male"|>
     , "home" -> <|"name"->"Jane","Sex"->"Female"|>
     |>
  }
}
*)
```

The result is a list of sublists, each sublist containing a two-level nested association from `first` and another such nested assocation from `second`.  We wish to produce a single merged association from each sublist:

`Assocation` will bring together two associations, discarding duplicate keys from the second:

```
Association[{<|"name"->"bob","money"->10|>, <|"name"->"bob","Sex"->"male"|>}]

(* <| "name"->"bob", "money"->10, "Sex"->"male" |> *)
```

`Merge` will bring together two associations, but instead of discarding values duplicate keys will use a function to compute a merged value.  Thus, we can use `Merge` in conjunction with `Association` from above to merge our `away/home` pairs:

```
{ <| "away" -> <|"name"->"bob","money"->10|>
   , "home" -> <|"name"->"Sue","money"->15|>
   |>
, <| "away" -> <|"name"->"bob","Sex"->"male"|>
   , "home" -> <|"name"->"Sue","sex"->"female"|>
   |>
} // Merge[Association]

(*
<| "away" -> <|"name"->"bob","money"->10,"Sex"->"male"|>
 , "home"-> <|"name"->"Sue","money"->15,"sex"->"female"|>
 |>
*)
```

We `Map` to perform this merge upon all sublists.  Putting it all together, we obtain our final expression:

```
GatherBy[Join[first, second], #[[All, "name"]] &] // Map[Merge[Association]]
```

This is essentially equivalent to `JoinAcross` with full-outer-join semantics.  If inner-join semantics are required, we need to add a stage that filters out unmatched elements:

```
GatherBy[Join[first, second], #[[All, "name"]] &] //
  Select[Length@# > 1 &] //
  Map[Merge[Association]]
```

Left- or right-outer-join semantics would require more elaborate filtering and is left as an exercise for the reader.

Answer (score 2):

Probably not general enough for you but works for the example:

```
MapThread[Merge[{##}, Join @@ # &] &, {first, second}]
```