# How to organically merge nested associations?

Tags: associations, gathering

Suppose I want to construct an association of associations, such as a list of people with attributes:

```
peopleFacts=<| alice-> <|age->29,shoeSize->7|>, bob-> <|age->27,sex->male|> |>
```

However, I want to grow and update this organically by adding facts as I learn them.

```
peopleFacts[["steve","hairColor"]] = "red";
peopleFacts[["bob","age"]] = "22";
peopleFacts[["steve","major"]] = "physics";
```

It's possible to accomplish this awkwardly by either (a) filling the database with blank entries or (b) laboriously checking at each level of association to see if an entry is blank before filling it in (except the last level, where `AssociateTo` helps you).  But I think there must be a more elegant way.  Here is what I've tried.

This method breaks because it tosses out the second key:

```
 In[]:= peopleFacts[["steve","hairColor"]] = "red";
        peopleFacts

Out[]:= <|steve -> red, alice-> <|age->29,shoeSize->7|>, bob-> <|age->27,sex->male|> |>
```

This method drops existing data:

```
 In[]:= peopleFacts

Out[]:= <| alice-> <|age->29,shoeSize->7|>, bob-> <|age->27,sex->male|> |>

 In[]:= AssociateTo[peopleFacts, alice-> <|"sport"->"baseball"|>;
        peopleFacts

Out[]:= <| alice-> <|sport->baseball|>, bob-> <|age->27,sex->male|> |>
```

This method just doesn't evaluate:

```
 In[]:= AssociateTo[peopleFacts[["chris"]], "favoriteFood" -> "sushi"]

Out[]:= AssociateTo[peopleFacts[["chris"]], "favoriteFood" -> "sushi"]
```

**EDIT**: Here is a way-too-awkward method adapted from [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/99340/1806) by SuTron.

```
 In[]:= peopleFacts

Out[]:= <| alice-> <|age->29,shoeSize->7|>, bob-> <|age->27,sex->male|> |>

 In[]:= Module[{temp = peopleFacts["alice"]},
          AssociateTo[temp, "sport"->"baseball"];
          AssociateTo[peopleFacts, "alice" -> temp];
        ];
        peopleFacts

Out[]:= <| alice-> <|age->29,shoeSize->7,sport->baseball|>, bob-> <|age->27,sex->male|> |>
```

It's not hard to imagine defining a custom update function like

```
  NestedAssociateTo[peopleFacts,{"steve","haircolor","red"}]
```

that would handle this all for you, but I'd much rather have a nice native Mathematica solution that is optimized, and that I don't have to maintain or worry about.

Comment: This question feels familiar but I can recall neither an answer nor the original I may be thinking of.  (For the sake of my own organization alone this is vaguely related: [(88442)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/88442/121))

Comment: Ahh, I think my question is essentially a special case of ([82915](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/80311/joinacross-on-nested-association-by-nested-key)), except that additional work is needed to generalize the answer to that question for arbitrary levels of nesting.

Comment: Seeing Kuba's solution I am reminded that these are at least distantly related:  [(83507)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/83507/121), 
[(86578)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/86578/121)

Comment: @JessRiedel - can you edit to make your symbols vs strings consistent? You have, both bob and "bob".

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Initial data:

```
peopleFacts = <|
    alice -> <|age -> 29, shoeSize -> 7|>, 
    bob -> <|age -> 27, sex -> male,  hair -> <|Color -> RGBColor[1, 0, 0]|>
    |>
|>;
```

---

Here is a version of `RecurAssocMerge` reduced to a single definition.

```
MergeNested = If[MatchQ[#, {__Association}], Merge[#, #0], Last[#]] &

MergeNested @ {peopleFacts, <|bob -> <|hair -> <|length -> 120|>|>|>}
```

> ```
>  <|
>    alice -> <|
>      age -> 29, 
>      shoeSize -> 7|>, 
>    bob -> <|
>      age -> 27, 
>      sex -> male,  
>      hair -> <|Color -> RGBColor[1, 0, 0], length -> 120|>
>    |>
>  |>
> ```

---

Special case of 2-level deep association

```
Merge[{
   peopleFacts,
   <|bob -> <|hairColor -> 1|>|>
 },
 Association
]
```

"Tidy" approach to write `NestedMerge`:

```
RecurAssocMerge[a : {__Association}] := Merge[a, RecurAssocMerge];
RecurAssocMerge[a_] := Last[a];
```

- adding key to deep level association:

  ```
  RecurAssocMerge[
    {peopleFacts, <|bob -> <|hair -> <|length -> 120|>|>|>}
   ]
  ```

  > ```
  >  <|alice -> <|age -> 29, shoeSize -> 7|>, 
  >    bob -> <|age -> 27, sex -> male, hair -> <|
  >         Color -> RGBColor[1, 0, 0], length -> 120 |>
  >    |>
  >  |>
  > ```
- entirely new tree

  ```
  RecurAssocMerge[
     {peopleFacts, <|kuba -> <|hair -> <|length -> 120|>|>|>}
   ]
  ```

  > ```
  >  <|
  >     alice -> <|age -> 29, shoeSize -> 7|>, 
  >     bob -> <|age -> 27, sex -> male, hair -> <|Color -> RGBColor[1, 0, 0]|>
  >     |>, 
  >     kuba -> <|hair -> <|length -> 120|>|>
  > |>
  > ```

---

Section added by Jess Riedel:

#### Specialize to single new entry

`RecurAssocMerge` defined above is a general method for merging nested `Associations`.  We can define an abbreviation for the special case when we are adding only a single new entry.

```
RecurAssocMerge[ini_Association, path_List, value_] := RecurAssocMerge[{
   ini, Fold[<|#2 -> #|> &, value, Reverse@path]
}]
```

Then we can just do

```
RecurAssocMerge[peopleFacts, {bob, hair, length}, 120]
```

> ```
>  <|alice -> <|age -> 29, shoeSize -> 7|>, 
>    bob -> <|age -> 27, sex -> male, hair -> <|
>             Color -> RGBColor[1, 0, 0], length -> 120 |>
>      |>
>    |>
> ```

#### Notes

If you want to modify `peopleFacts` the `peopleFacts = Merge...` is needed of course.

Comment: how to modify your code if it is not known per se on what level of Association to Merge? (I mean, if bob is nested deeper?)

Comment: `Merge` is a good solution. Would be good if it had `HoldFirst` as the structure could be come big.

Comment: @Kuba, can you please modify your answer to show the general case where the Associations are nested to deeper levels?  I don't understand your comment to @garej about using `GroupBy`.

Comment: Suppose initially  `peopleFacts = <|alice -> <|age -> 29|>, 
  bob -> <|music -> <|rock -> rollingStones|>|>|>` and I want to add `<|bob -> <|music -> <|rap -> kanye|>|>|>` to get `peopleFacts = <|alice -> <|age -> 29|>,  bob -> <|music -> <|rock -> rollingStones, rap -> kanye|>|>|>`.  This is subtle, because the decision to append rather than replace at the level "music" depends on the fact that the `Value` associated with `Key` "music" is of type `Association`.

Comment: @Kuba Very elegant.  Your solution is extremely general since, as you note in your heading, this can merge two arbitrarily nested Associations.  My initial question about adding individual elements is just a special case.  I find this so useful I suggest you pose a new Mathematica.SE question "How to recursively merge nested Associations?" and answer it yourself.  If you don't, I'll do for you and cite you.  Many thanks!

Comment: @JessRiedel, what if `bob` is not in the upper level? is it interesting for you? Say, `sample3 = <|people -> <|bob -> <|age -> <|male -> 23, female -> 20|>, sex -> male|>|>|>` and to add `f[{sample3, <|bob -> <|age -> 10|>|>}]`

Comment: @garej In general that's an ambiguous situation, since `bob` could appear at several places in the tree, and at different levels.  One would have to construct a function that recursively searches the *entire* tree, whereas my initial request was when the correct location is fully specified (so that the evaluation is efficient even when the tree is very large).  It would be an interesting problem, though.

Comment: @JessRiedel, I see. Anyway, You've posted very nice question +1.

Comment: @Kuba I have suggested an edit that tidies up your answer to be more useful to future readers. (I don't think keeping track of what's an edit is import now that the problem is solved; people can always check the revision history.)  Please accept it if you think it's appropriate.

Comment: @JessRiedel Accepted after corrections. There were some undefined functions in the last section. But I've changed it anyway to something more compact. Also, there were string keys in the last example while everything is done on symbols, so I dropped them to be consistent. I'd call the function `MergeNestedAssociation` but that is not important. And finally, thanks for the edit! :)

Comment: @JessRiedel Please take a look at the edit on top of the answer, you may find it entertaining ;)

Comment: Very nice extensions.

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Thanks :) Have a nice holidays, I hope you are well, I noticed you were relatively inactive lately. Best :)

Comment: @Kuba Thank you!  Merry Christmas.  :-)  I am well, but as noted taking a break from posting.

Comment: v.useful, succinct solution of what would seem to be a common idiom (perhaps justifying a system implementation to accommodate the OP's initial tendency: `peopleFacts[["bob","hair","Length"]] = "red"`)
Related to [2249](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/91331/2249) and implements the advocated use of `Part` to "Creatively Set" values in `List`\`s/`Association`\`s (or with operator form 
`peopleFacts @= CreativeSet[{"bob", "hair", "Length"}, "red"]` where 
`CreativeSet[pos_,value_] := Function[a,RecurAssocMerge[a, pos,value]]`)

Answer (score 16):

### **Update**

Created an `upsert` function to update/insert new keys and values into a nested association structure. It automatically *inserts* nested associations where they do not exists and does not need to be assigned back to the original association. It *updates* existing keys when they are found.

```
ClearAll[upsert]
Attributes[upsert] = {HoldFirst};
upsert[dat_?AssociationQ, key_, value__] :=
 If[First@Dimensions@{value} == 1,
  dat[key] = value,
  (
   If[KeyExistsQ[dat, key] == False, dat[key] = <||>];
   upsert[dat[key], First@{value}, Sequence @@ Rest@{value}]
  )
  ]
```

Can use `upsert` with as many nested levels as needed.

```
peopleFacts = <|"alice" -> <|"age" -> 29, "shoeSize" -> 7|>, 
   "bob" -> <|"age" -> 27, "sex" -> "male"|>|>;
```

*Insert* `"steve"` and association `"haircolor"` key/value.

```
upsert[peopleFacts, "steve", "haircolor", "Red"];
peopleFacts

(* <|"alice" -> <|"age" -> 29, "shoeSize" -> 7|>, 
 "bob" -> <|"age" -> 27, "sex" -> "male"|>, 
 "steve" -> <|"haircolor" -> "Red"|>|> *)
```

*Insert* `"tim"`, association `"music"` key/value, and nested association `"rock"` key/value.

```
upsert[peopleFacts, "tim", "music", "rock", "jimmy"];
peopleFacts

(* <|"alice" -> <|"age" -> 29, "shoeSize" -> 7|>, 
 "bob" -> <|"age" -> 27, "sex" -> "male"|>, 
 "steve" -> <|"haircolor" -> "Red"|>, 
 "tim" -> <|"music" -> <|"rock" -> "jimmy"|>|>|> *)
```

*Update* `"alice"` `"age"`.

```
upsert[peopleFacts, "alice", "age", 25];
peopleFacts

(* <|"alice" -> <|"age" -> 25, "shoeSize" -> 7|>, 
 "bob" -> <|"age" -> 27, "sex" -> "male"|>, 
 "steve" -> <|"haircolor" -> "Red"|>, 
 "tim" -> <|"music" -> <|"rock" -> "lenny"|>|>|> *)
```

---

**Original Post**

Each time there is a new key that has an association as its value you must initialise it as an association. Then you can use the feature of `Association` that creates a key when a value is assigned to a non-existing key.

```
peopleFacts = <|"alice" -> <|"age" -> 29, "shoeSize" -> 7|>, "bob" -> <|"age" -> 27, "sex" -> "male"|>|>;

peopleFacts["steve"] = <||>;
peopleFacts
(* <|alice -> <|age -> 29, shoeSize -> 7|>, 
 bob -> <|age -> 27, sex -> male|>, steve -> <||>|> *)

peopleFacts["steve"]["hairColor"] = "Red";
peopleFacts
(* <|alice -> <|age -> 29, shoeSize -> 7|>, 
 bob -> <|age -> 27, sex -> male|>, steve -> <|hairColor -> Red|>|> *)

peopleFacts["bob"]["age"] = 22;
peopleFacts
(* <|alice -> <|age -> 29, shoeSize -> 7|>, 
 bob -> <|age -> 22, sex -> male|>, steve -> <|hairColor -> Red|>|> *)

peopleFacts["steve"]["major"] = "Physics";
peopleFacts
(* <|alice -> <|age -> 29, shoeSize -> 7|>, 
 bob -> <|age -> 22, sex -> male|>, 
 steve -> <|hairColor -> "Red", major -> "Physics"|>|> *)
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I'm afraid this doesn't help much.  Using your method, I have to check whether I'm writing over existing data, right?  If I already have a bunch of facts about `steve`, then initializing `peopleFacts[steve] = <||>` erases them all.

Comment: When you say "Each time there is a new key that has an association as its value you must initialise it as an association", are you just unaware of a more elegant method, or do you have some reason to be sure none exists?

Comment: @JessRiedel You can use `KeyExistsQ` to check.

Comment: I know, but that becomes very cumbersome if you're adding elements to a database that's several layers nested.

Comment: @JessRiedel I've updated and added a small `upsert` function that handles the nesting and key creation.

Comment: Thanks!  Could you explain more what `HoldFirst` accomplishes in this situation?

Comment: `HoldFirst` passes the first parameter by reference. This prevents a copy of it begin created (would eat up memory for large items). It also allows the association passed in to be directly updated (no need to assign back to the original association).

Comment: @Edmund, can you try the list `sample3 = <|people -> <|
    bob -> <|age -> <|male -> 23, female -> 20|>, sex -> male|>|>|>` with the following command `upsert[sample3, "bob", "age", "10"]`.

Comment: `bob` is not equal to `"bob"`. One is a string and the other is a symbol. Also, your path states that you want a new key at the top level of `"bob"`.

Comment: @Edmund, that was just an artefact of copy-paste; `{bob, age, 10}` is the case. Nevermind =)

Comment: I noticed that you used dat_?AssociationQ instead of dat_Association.  From my experiments with a List first argument this seems to be necessary.  Can someone explain why?

Comment: @JohnMcGee It is because `dat` is being passed by `HoldFirst` so it is a pointer to a position in memory not a copy of the actual object. Therefore the memory pointer in `dat` must be inspected to discover what it is pointing to. This is what `AssociationQ` does. It takes the pointer and inspects the `Head` of what it points to.

Comment: @Edmund - Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Try this, we're using it on a daily basis

```
Nest[Merge,f,n]
```

To your starting data, slightly modified (strings vs symbols):

```
peopleFacts = <|"alice" -> <|"age" -> 29, "shoeSize" -> 7|>, 
   "bob" -> <|"age" -> 27, "sex" -> "male"|>|>;
```

And new facts:

```
newFacts = <|
  "steve" -> <|"hairColor" -> "red", "major" -> "physics"|>,
  "bob" -> <|"age" -> 22|>|>
```

Update semantics for replacing existing values: (1) add newFacts last, (2) apply `Last` eg:

```
{peopleFacts, newFacts} // Nest[Merge, Last, 2]
```

> <|"alice" -> <|"age" -> 29, "shoeSize" -> 7|>,   "bob" -> <|"age" ->
>   22, "sex" -> "male"|>,   "steve" -> <|"hairColor" -> "red", "major" ->
>   "physics"|>|>

Keep in mind `Merge` does not yet have full complement of options like `JoinAcross` eg inner/outer/left/right and will not impute missing keys, so often `KeyIntersection` is required.

Also will admit for some types of ragged hierarchies, there's no current easy way to merge all relevant branches automatically (an `All` level spec). In other words, knowledge of the schema is required.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/63346/discussion-between-kuba-and-alancalvitti).

Comment: @Kuba, chat is frozen - just added a recursive approach based on your answer. Let me know if you find it useful. This is the 3rd example of query recursion that I'd like to present @ WTC.

Comment: Can't focus too much on this topic atm. Does it do anything more than my `MergeNested`? Or is there any reason to prefer one over another? Performance? Flexibility? Because readability goes for `MergeNested` I guess.

Comment: I think the way you defined `MergeNested` it only works on 2 levels  - if so the comparison should be made to the general recursive version.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. The example is already 3 level deep: `<|bob -> <|hair -> <|length -> 120|>|>|>`. Could you elaborate?

Comment: Would `MergeNested` work on arbitrary-depth `Associations`? If so, what's the point of `RecurAssocMerge`

Comment: It should and both should work the same, the former is one line pure function and the latter is a set of downvalues in a more readable form. The last section was added by Jess so it may be confusing.

Comment: Ok I see the recursion set up by #0. I tested MergeNested on a deeply nested Association and it works - but beware if it's not wrapped up in a Query it fails when composed inside a Dataset, eg `ds[All,Values/*MergeNested]`

Answer (score 2):

This recursive Query is inspired by Kuba's answer:

```
nestedMerge[f_] := 
  Query[Merge[Identity] /* 
    Query[All, {MatchQ[{__Association}], Identity} /* 
      Replace[{{True, data_} :> 
         nestedMerge[f][data], {False, data_} :> Query[f][data]} ]]];
```

Test on peopleFacts - note appended data is rewritten as nested `Association` vs OP:

```
{peopleFacts, <|steve -> <|hairColor -> red|>|>, <|
    bob -> <|age -> 22|>|>, <|steve -> <|major -> physics|>|>} // 
  nestedMerge[Last] // Dataset
```

[image]