# Merging nested associations. A better way to do this?

Tags: associations

Suppose I have these two associations:

```
association1=<|
               "a" -> <|"b" -> <|"c" -> "txt1"|> |>,
               "d" -> <|"e" -> <|"f" -> "txt2"|> |>
             |>;

association2=<|
               "a" -> <|"b" -> <| "C" -> "TXT1"|> |>,
               "d" -> <|"e" -> <| "F" -> "TXT2"|> |>
             |>;
```

And I want to merge them. Notice that the keys at the first two levels are the same, so the merging needs to happen at the third level. The expected result is:

```
<|
  "a" -> <|"b" -> <|"c" -> "txt1", "C" -> "TXT1"|> |>,
  "d" -> <|"e" -> <|"f" -> "txt2", "F" -> "TXT2"|> |>
|>
```

Is there a elegant way of doing this? The best I have come up with is:

```
Merge[{association1, association2}, 
      Merge[#, Merge[#, Identity] &] &
     ] /. {x_String} :> x
```

A merge inside a merge inside a merge and then post process it with a replacement rule. This makes me think that there must be a better way to do this simple operation.

Notice that the depth of the associations is 4 not 3 like in the related

*Update*: There is a related question at [How to organically merge nested associations?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/102466/how-to-organically-merge-nested-associations) involving associations with Depth[peopleFacts] of 3. In my question the associations have a depth of 4, so I think this is not a duplicate.

Comment: The OP in the related question expressly requested (in comments) that the solution must work to arbitrary depth.  Kuba's `MergeNested` [solution](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/102483/142) fulfills that requirement and produces the result you want.

Comment: In my case, I don't want it to work for an arbitrary depth (unless it is simpler than xavier response). I want the simplest possible way of merging associations with the structure shown.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With one `Merge` less, and using the operator form of `Merge`:

```
Merge[{association1, association2}, Merge[Association]]

(* <|
     "a" -> <|"b" -> <|"c" -> "txt1", "C" -> "TXT1"|>|>, 
     "d" -> <|"e" -> <|"f" -> "txt2", "F" -> "TXT2"|>|>
   |> *)
```

Comment: Ahh.. this looks much better. Thank you xavier.