# Convert association with list key to nested assocations

Tags: associations, gathering

I have an association that maps `{x, y}` pairs to values, for example:

```
 <|{0, 0} -> "a", {-1, -4} -> "b", {-1, 1} -> "c", {-1, 0} -> "d", {1, 0} -> "e"|>
```

I want to convert this to a nested association with the outer association keyed by `x` and the inner by `y`:

```
<|0 -> <|0 -> "a"|>, -1 -> <|-4 -> "b", 0 -> "d", 1 -> "c"|>, 1 -> <|0 -> "e"|>|>
```

My current code is (assuming `a` is the association):

```
Apply[Association]@*Map[Last@# -> a[#] &] /@ GroupBy[Keys@a, First, Sort]
```

but I'm wondering if there's a more elegant way to do this (sorting not necessary).

Comment: You could also use `Association /@` rather than `Apply[Association]@*` in your code with same results.

Answer (score 8):

The following will do the same thing and avoid the sorting, but I am not sure whether it counts as "more elegant" in your book:

```
assoc = <|{0, 0} -> "a", {-1, -4} -> "b", {-1, 1} -> "c", {-1, 0} -> "d", {1, 0} -> "e"|>;

Association /@
 GroupBy[#[[1, 1]]& -> (#[[1, 2]] -> #[[2]] &)]@
  Normal@assoc

(*Out:  <|0 -> <|0 -> "a"|>, -1 -> <|-4 -> "b", 1 -> "c", 0 -> "d"|>, 1 -> <|0 -> "e"|>|> *)
```

Comment: It avoids referencing the association twice, so it's definitely better than the original.

Answer (score 7):

```
Merge[
    KeyValueMap[ #[[1]] -> <|#[[2]] -> #2|> &, asso]
  , Association
]
```

> ```
> <|0 -> <|0 -> "a"|>, -1 -> <|-4 -> "b", 1 -> "c", 0 -> "d"|>,  1 -> <|0 -> "e"|>|>
> ```

For deeper examples `{1,2,3,4,1}->"a"` etc, you may need [**`MergeNested`**](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/102483/5478)

Comment: Kuba, is NestedMerge a new function? It's not documented, or do you mean `Nest[Merge,f,n]`

Comment: @alancalvitti I linked it, click it :)

Comment: my fault, I thought false highlighting. What are the advantages of NestedMerge viz Nest[Merge,...]?

Comment: Btw, can you email me re WTC this year if you're going - re planned get together in C-U or Chi? Your contact info lists gluonvision but only Rolf's email shows up there.

Comment: @alancalvitti due to personal matters I can't go this year. Would love to meet fellow MMA users again but maybe next year.

Answer (score 1):

```
keyTrie=Query[keyGroupBy[First]]/*Query[All,KeyMap[Rest]]/*Query[All,If[Keys[#1]=={{}},First[Values[#1]],keyTrie[#1]]&]
```

This is a recursive query that uses `keyGroupBy` utility:

```
keyGroupBy[f_][expr_]:=Association/@GroupBy[Normal[expr],Keys/*f]
```

To your data:

```
<|{0, 0} -> "a", {-1, -4} -> "b", {-1, 1} -> "c", {-1, 0} -> 
   "d", {1, 0} -> "e"|> // keyTrie
```

> <|0 -> <|0 -> "a"|>, -1 -> <|-4 -> "b", 1 -> "c", 0 -> "d"|>,   1 ->
>   <|0 -> "e"|>|>