# Hierarchically adding {...keys..}->value to an association

Tags: programming, associations

Given a list of keys `{"a","b","c"}` and a value `3` (associated to the last key) I want to define a function that is equivalent to this manual procedure:

```
w=<||>;
w["a"]=<||>;
w["a"]["b"]=<||>;
w["a"]["b"]["c"]=3;
w
```

prints:

```
<|"a" -> <|"b" -> <|"c" -> 3|>|>|>
```

From  `{"a","b","c"}->3`, it must create keys/values going deeper in the hierarchy.

---

The solution I have written so far is:

```
setKeyValue[assoc_Association,{keys___,keyLast_}->value_]:=
    Block[{tmp,var,keysAsList},
          keysAsList={keys};
          tmp=FoldList[If[KeyExistsQ[#1,#2],#1[#2],<||>]&,assoc,keysAsList];
          tmp=Reverse[Partition[Riffle[Prepend[keysAsList,Null],tmp],2]];
          tmp=Fold[{First[#2],(var=Last[#2];AssociateTo[var,First[#1]->Last[#1]])}&,{keyLast,value},tmp];
          Last[tmp]
    ];
```

Example with expected behavior:

```
v=<||>;
v=setKeyValue[v,{"a","b","c"}->3]
v=setKeyValue[v,{"a","b","e","f"}->6]
```

prints

```
<|"a" -> <|"b" -> <|"c" -> 3|>|>|>
<|"a" -> <|"b" -> <|"c" -> 3, "e" -> <|"f" -> 6|>|>|>|>
```

However this function looks so over-complicated that I am sure it exists  a more elegant approach.

Any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `MergeNested` from [How to organically merge nested associations?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/102466/5478) we can define `AssociateNested`:

```
MergeNested = If[MatchQ[#, {__Association}], Merge[#, #0], Last[#]] &;

AssociateNested[org_Association, path_List, value_] := MergeNested[
  {org, Fold[<|#2 -> #|> &, value, Reverse@path]}
]
```

Example:

```
v = <||>;

v = AssociateNested[v, {"a", "b", "c"}, 3]
```

> ```
> <|"a" -> <|"b" -> <|"c" -> 3|>|>|>
> ```

```
v = AssociateNested[v, {"a", "b", "e", "f"}, 6]
```

> ```
> <|"a" -> <|"b" -> <|"c" -> 3, "e" -> <|"f" -> 6|>|>|>|>
> ```

Comment: That's much shorter indeed, thanks

Comment: The solution works, however I do not understand the reason of using the recursive MergeNested. The simpler `AssociateNested[org_Association, path_List, value_] := Merge[{org, Fold[<|#2 -> #|> &, value, Reverse@path]},Association]` seems to work too. There is certainly something I miss. May you provide some clarification?

Comment: @PicaudVincent isn't `"c" -> 3` gone after the second call?

Comment: yep, I have not seen that, thanks for the clarification